# How to remove auth text in facebook share

Tags: reactjs, facebook-share

React.js facebook share code.

```
    <FacebookProvider appId="498840760997247">
    <div className="image-wrapper">
    <img src={"/assets/social_Icons/facebook.svg"} alt="fb-icon" width="20px" height="20px" />
    <ShareButton href={`${constants.URL}/sharing/share/?id=${id}`} quote="smartshop">
        <span>Share to Facebook</span>
    </ShareButton>
    </div>
    </FacebookProvider>
```

I am using below package.

```
    https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook
```

Please check attached photo. In the marked area it is coming text auth.
How can i change it to something else.

I am trying to add smartshop instead but it is not working
[image]